# Circular project visualisation tool that resembles a cross between Gantt and pregnancy calculator disc

Tags: tools, gantt, timeline

I find it hard to visualise projects across the years on a Gantt chart, especially when there are seasonal tasks repeating.

It would be nice to have a tool that looks like a pregnancy calculator disc, that emphasises the repeating of seasons, etc:

[image]

Is there any formal type of diagram or tool that does that?

Answer (score 1):

The reliability in pregnancy is much higher than any type of work task.  It is 266 days from conception, with only a very small variability except when you have something that is abnormal.  Task duration is not like that, where "normal" can have a much larger range.  Therefore, creating a tool like this for work would have an extremely low reliability and, therefore, validity.

Comment: I'm not suggesting static time allocation. This is pretty much a Gantt chart that is "bent" instead of horizontal, and there should definitely be room for variability :)